# Is there a Loyalty Bonus for having saves of the previous games on the same device / device line?

Tags: borderlands-3

Is there a Loyalty Bonus for having saves of the previous games on the same device / device line?

Like how the Pre-Sequel gave moonstones and weapons for having the previous games?

Comment: Of course, you gain more [pride](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/bnik3d/bonuses_for_owning_entire_franchise/) ;) And you know all and each old character in personal, really cool during first playthrough... unless you download someone else saves..

Answer (score 4):

Well, just to get this out of the Unanswered list, apparently no, there are no loyalty bonuses.

Which is good for first-timers of the franchise... at least.

Comment: You did this for the hat didn't you?

Comment: @Sorean - I don't have... What is there a hat for answering a self-question? No, I just want to hit 2500.

Comment: I was browsing hats earlier and the Tenacious one is defined as "Write a good self-answer to an old question" and just happened to see this :D